# Unable to view database object in django in html

Tags: python, html, django

The object in the database is not visible in the html.

Model

```
class OutFormatTemplate(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    template = models.FileField(upload_to='out_put_temp/')

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.title}"
```

View

```
def upload_form(request):
    out_form = OutFormatTemplate.objects.all()
    for i in out_form:
        print(i.id, i.title)
    form = UploadBookForm()
    context = {
        'form': form,
        'outform': out_form
    }
    return render(request, 'file_uploader.html', context)
```

HTML

```
{% if outfrom %}
    <p>Out Form Exist</p>
{% else %}
    <p>Not Exist</p>
{% endif %}
<div class="mt-2" id="out-template">
    <label for="template-out" class="form-label">Select Output Template</label>
    <select class="form-select" aria-label="Default out select example" name="out_template_id" id="template-out">
        <option value="0" selected></option>
        {% for out in outfrom %}
        <option value="{{ out.id }}">{{ out.title }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
</div>
```

The database value

[Table values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1k5Dg.png)

But in the webpage these values are not shown

[Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbFLK.png)

Iam new to django, I need help. Have i done anything wrong here.

Comment: Your context says 'outform' whilst your template has 'outfrom' - that might be why

Comment: Please do not use images, instead insert f.i. your table as code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is look like you have a typo, where you are naming the variable in the context (outform) but in your template you are calling (outfrom).